# spark uses sophisticated ways to leverage memory space - explain

Tags: apache-spark, garbage-collection, jvm

I was watching a video on apache spark [here](https://youtu.be/EuWDz2Vb1Io?t=7064) . Where the speaker Paco Nathan says the following

> "If you have 128 GB of RAM, you are not going to throw them all at once at the jvm.That will just cause a lot of garbage collection. And so one of the things with spark is, use more sophisticated ways to leverage the memory space, do more off-heap."

I am not able to understand what he says with regard to how spark efficiently handles this scenario.

also more specifically i completely did not understand the statement

> "If you have 128 GB of RAM you are not going to throw them all at once at the jvm.That will just cause of lot of garbage collection"

Can someone explain what the reasoning actually is behind these statements ?

Comment: You might find Chronicle Queue and Map interesting as it does allow you thrown hundreds of GB at a single JVM. The largest is around 100 TB in one JVM. Disclaimer; I helped write it.

Comment: I will try to explain more careful in future talks. This feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> "If you have 128 GB of RAM you are not going to throw them all at once
>   at the jvm.That will just cause of lot of garbage collection"

This means that you will not assign all the memory to the JVM only when there is memory requirement for other stuff like garbage collection, off-heap operations, etc.

Spark does this by assigning fractions of the memory(that you have assigned to Spark executors) for such operations as shown in image below(for Spark 1.5.0):

[image]